# How to convert getRecordTypeInfosByName in Apex to web service?

Tags: c#, soap, salesforce, apex-code, force.com

I am moving some code out of Apex to web services using the Enterprise WSDL. There is a line of code that I cannot find the equivalent to in the web service but I am hoping it is there. How would I convert this to a method from `SforceService`?

```
var client = Schema.SObjectType.Lead.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Business Clients').getRecordTypeId();
```

I am trying to do this in C# but am ok if you can help me find it in `SforceService`. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call [describeSObject()](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_describesobject.htm#kanchor751) on Lead.  That will return a [DescribeSObjectResult](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_describesobjects_describesobjectresult.htm#topic-title) with an array of [RecordTypeInfos](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_describesobjects_describesobjectresult.htm#i1428028).  You can iterate through the RecordTypeInfos and find the one with the name you want, and get its corresponding ID there.